# JdbcOperator with Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow

I am trying to write multiple sql statements in JdbcOperator and not sure how to use template; Or delimiter of many sql strings.
The code below says TemplateNotFound. I created "templates" folder at same level as "dags"

```
sql_task = JdbcOperator(
    task_id='sql_cmd',
    jdbc_conn_id='hive_connection',
    template_searchpath='/etc/dev/airflow/templates',
    sql='all_sql.sql',
    params={"db":'devl_df2_tsa_batch'},
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Try *logging* the **current `$PYTHONPATH`** in your *`DAG`-definition-file* using `print("sys.path:-\n{}", *(sys.path), sep="\n")` and maybe then use **relative-`import`**? I had once referenced external files placed in `../airflow/dags/my_dir/my_file.txt` using `my_dir/my_file.txt` (`my_dir` was inside `dags` directory, not *alongside* it as in your case)

Comment: I got a bit further just doing like you said, with templates inside dags; Now the question is how to write the sql file. I have tried separating queries by semicolon but that did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it in the following ways:

**List**:

```
sql_task = JdbcOperator(
    task_id='sql_cmd',
    jdbc_conn_id='hive_connection',
    template_searchpath='/etc/dev/airflow/templates',
    sql=['select * from table1', 'select * from table2'],
    params={"db":'devl_df2_tsa_batch'},
    dag=dag
)
```

OR

**SQL File**

```
sql_task = JdbcOperator(
    task_id='sql_cmd',
    jdbc_conn_id='hive_connection',
    template_searchpath='/etc/dev/airflow/templates',
    sql=['templates/test1.sql','templates/test2.sql'],
    params={"db":'devl_df2_tsa_batch'},
    dag=dag
)
```

where `templates/test1.sql`, `templates/test2.sql` file are inside `dags` folder and each containing 1 query.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kaxil, will try that.